# Why can't I reach other devices on WiFi network that doesn't have internet access?

Tags: wi-fi, connection-issues

My phone with Android 11 is connected to a hotspot on my laptop that does not have internet access (on purpose). In the quick settings it shows a little cross next to the WiFi icon, the status bar doesn't show it at all, only a 4G icon that data is active.

Other devices on the hotspot can ping the phone and successfully send datagram packets to it (via a custom app) but the phone cannot ping them and its datagram packets don't reach the network (can't see them with Wireshark).

The only way the phone is able to reach the devices is when I turn off data connection, so it can only route the packets through the WiFi network. Is there another way that would allow me to keep data on so I can have internet access? The subnets don't overlap and I can't think of any other reason the packets would be lost. I believe this is some Android-specific issue.

Comment: Check your `ip rule` and `ip route`. Most probably you'll need to manually adjust routing table to achieve what you want. Manipulating network routing requires root access.